# Setup one Jenkins to have another Jenkins send an email

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins servers A and B, running in separate networks. "A" server also contains our SVN. "A" runs our common Jenkins Builds, whereas "B" is mostly used for deployments. However, server "A" does not have access (I think) to our SMTP server, whereas "B" does.

Is it possible to setup "A" and "B" so that "A" builds a job and if it fails, it somehow triggers "B" to send an email to developers who broke the build? The email sending has previously been done on server "B" only, so I am unsure whether:
1) B can somehow be triggered by A, and
2) if B can somehow get the list of email addresses from A to whom the email should be sent to

Comment: is A able to see B ? If yes, you should just set up some port forward from B to the smtp server, only available to A. Keep it simple.

Comment: I think this is not a move our client would allow us to make